# How do I use the IP of a container as an ENV var of another container

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, rabbitmq

I am trying to set up a docker-compose file where I have 2 services. There is a RabbitMQ broker and a publisher/consumer. In the code of the publisher/consumer, I set the connection up using an IP from the os environment variables. However, I am not sure how I can get the IP of a different container, and set it in the ENV variable.

Comment: I'd suggest reading [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.  As @zsolt indicates in their answer, the Compose service names are usable as DNS names to communicate between containers.  You never need to directly know the container-private IP addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the compose service name instead of ip.